# Why composer uses other PHP version then php command points to?

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

Here's my environment configuration (Ubuntu).

I have installed PHP 5.5.9 version via apt-get, and using PHPBrew also installed version 7.0.6. The PHP7 version is turned on.

```
$ which php
/home/username/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.6/bin/php

$ php -v
PHP 7.0.6 (cli) (built: May 12 2016 08:54:46) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

I have composer installed globally by putting it in proper directory:

```
$ which composer
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

Now, when I run `composer require <something>`, it uses PHP 5.5.9 and returns error like (when the package being installed requires it of course):

```
Problem 1
  - This package requires php >=5.6.0 but your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Why doesn't composer use PHP version proper for current CLI configuration?

Please note that my question is **why** it happens and not **how** to solve the problem, because I've found already a few workarounds for that. I want to understand what happens here.

Comment: What does `cat /usr/local/bin/composer` output?

Comment: @h2ooooooo `composer.phar`'s content (php code).

Comment: probably because composer is installed globally, and takes the globally installed php version, while you have a 'custom' / local version in your home folder. Do you have su permissions on the system?

Comment: Yes, I have. And PHPBrew indeed changes `php` alias only for current user. But I'm running composer as this user.